# Is there a way to delete all Hotmail contacts at once?

Tags: outlook.com

The reason is that some spam emails are sent automatically to my contacts, and I don't use this address any more.

So, if there isn't a way to remove all contacts, is there a way at least to stop these emails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Microsoft Outlook to delete contacts in a few minutes without clicking through every contact.

Steps:

1. Add Hotmail account to Outlook.
2. If Microsoft Social Connector is not installed you will be prompted. After install finished. Restart Outlook and finish adding Hotmail acct.
3. Go to contacts. Look for Contact folder related to Hotmail. All your contacts are here.
4. Select all contacts (Ctrl-A)
5. Delete
6. Send/Receive
7. Feel free to delete Hotmail acct and uninstall social connector

Answer (score 1):

Use this autohotkey macro & modify this code to fit your case

```
WinWait, People - Google Chrome, 
IfWinNotActive, People - Google Chrome, , WinActivate, People - Google Chrome, 
WinWaitActive, People - Google Chrome, 

Loop 17 {
Send, {Tab}
}

Loop 200 {
Send, {DOWN}{SPACE}{DOWN}
sleep,500
}
```

Comment: it is intended to select 200 contacts, you can change this number as you need then you perform the delete operation , note chrome is used it should be opened and contacts link opened.

Comment: modification 

Loop 200 {
Send,{SPACE}{DOWN}
sleep,400
}

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way of doing this.

I'd recommend writing a script or macro to click automatically in the right places, with time delays between each click.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Outlook? You can try to use the [Hotmail Outlook connector](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/microsoft-office-outlook-hotmail-connector-overview-HA010222518.aspx), thereby syncing your Hotmail to Outlook (via a new profile) and then in *theory*, deleting your new profile's contacts in Outlook should sync to Hotmail, therefore deleting from Hotmail.

Or, if you don't use the email any more, close the account?

Or, and this is nearly deleting them all at once (depending on how many you have) but is still quite laborious but it does at least offer the ability to do so via the web interface without having Outlook installed.

Sign in to Outlook.com/Hotmail.com
Click on People (on the top left it shows Outlook, click on the drop down arrow to select people)
Here, you can select all the contacts you wish (don't wish) and they will appear on the right side of the screen. Above these, is the option to delete as the group).
It only displays X records at any point so if you've got a lot of contacts, this is probably not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no option to delete all your contacts at once. As of the moment clicking All and deleting them page by page is the only way.

**Note:** If your Hotmail account is sync with other services like Facebook you can unlink first from this services to remove the sync contacts to lessen the contacts you will be deleting.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In Hotmail outlook mode, select people. Then do not select any item on the list. Hold shift and click on first item. Continue holding shift key and press Page down key. (Or try End key).

Answer (score 0):

sign in on your Hotmail account,click on the OUTLOOK sign(on left)it will schroll down 
click on  (people)it will show you your contacts then you can delete which ones you want.i have just done this procedure and works.
hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question of how to delete them all at once...

Answer (score -1):

You could probably do it with a client of some sort. For example the Windows Live Mail program that downloads and installs on your computer. Or if you connect to hotmail using a fairly modern smart phone.